# Uncurry ramdajs function

Tags: javascript, ramda.js, currying

I have the follow data structure:

```
const cluster = {
    processes: [
        { color: 'test', x: 0, y: 0 },
        ...
    ],
};
```

And now I want to make function with the follow notation:

```
// getProcess :: (Cluster, number) -> Process
getProcess(cluster, 0);
// => { color: 'test', x: 0, y: 0 }
```

Well I try to use ramdajs for this:

```
const getProcess = R.compose(R.flip(R.nth), R.prop('processes'));
```

It is work fine for `getProcess(cluster)(0)` but for `getProcess(cluster, 0)` it return a function.

Is there way to solve this problem with ramda or may be more correct implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`R.uncurryN`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#uncurryN) to achieve this, which just takes the number of arguments you want to uncurry along with the curried function.

```
const getProcess = R.uncurryN(2, R.compose(R.flip(R.nth), R.prop('processes')));
```

This works with all curried functions, whether produced by Ramda or explicitly like the following.

```
R.uncurryN(2, x => y => x + y)
```

An alternative way to write this succinctly is with `R.useWith`, though I tend to find the use of `useWith` less readable than the alternatives.

```
const getProcess = R.useWith(R.nth, [R.identity, R.prop('processes')])
getProcess(0, cluster)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's what I looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the more direct approach is preferable..

```js
const getProcess = R.curry(
  (pos, entity) => R.path(['processes', pos], entity)
);
```